# Setting meta data tags with piexif

Tags: python, metadata, jpeg, exif

I try to set specific meta data for jpegs with the piexif module. I get the respective dicts out of the piexif.load().

`data = piexif.load()`.

They return {'GPS': {}, 'Exif': {}, 'Interop': {}, 'thumbnail': None, '1st': {}, '0th': {}}. (Maybe the answer is very obviouse but I am a little confused to the dicts)

However, I would like to know where and what to write to set my focus length, the camera maker and model.

The reason for that, I want to use the Regard3D reconstruction GUI from http://www.regard3d.org/index.php/documentation/details/picture-set.

Therefore, I need to add the meta to the jpegs and the data of the camera into the camera db. This is needed for the triangulation step.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Tags are different in the standard than in the tutorial. They supposed to be Make, Model, Focal Length in the EXIF format.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is a limit to what can be done with piexif. Although, I was unable to find camera make/model. 
However, you should be able to access the focal length like this. 
(Of course there are multiple ways to achieve this. This was just what I came up with)

```
import piexif
from PIL import Image


img = Image.open('input filename or path')

# Defining dictionary
exif_dict = piexif.FocalLength(img.info["exif"])

if piexif.ExifIFD.FocalLength in exif_dict["Exif"]:
    print("Current Focal Length is ", exif_dict["Exif"][piexif.ExifIFD.FocalLength])
else:
    print("No Focal Length is set")

# Getting User Input
fl = input("Enter a Focal Length: ")

# Applying user variable
exif_dict["Exif"][piexif.ExifIFD.LensMake] = fl

# Converting to bytes
exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)

#Saving Image
img.save("output filename or path", exif=exif_bytes)
```

There does look to be a lens make and lens model though.

```
piexif.ExifIFD.LensMake
piexif.ExifIFD.LensModel
```

Also, it might be worth noting that this value may not be changeable on some images and sometimes updating the value for an image does not seem to apply to the same field that would be displayed in windows 10 ui. I'm unsure if this is a bug or a compatibility issue with the image I was testing.

You also may want to check the [piexif docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/piexif/latest/piexif.pdf) as there might be more information on it as well.